# Can overtraining occur when I'm alternating muscle groups?

Tags: workout-routines, bodyweight-exercises, overtraining

I started working out and I'm doing only bodyweight exercises with progressions from convict conditioning book. The workout routine in this book was not intense enough for me. I read on many websites that I, as a beginner, should train each muscle group 3 times per week. So, I alternate between muscle groups every other day.

My workout routine is as follows:
M/W/F: Pull ups & squats 3 sets per exercise
T/T/S: Push ups & leg raises 3 sets per exercises
and sunday is off.

So, does this routine overtrain my body ?

Comment: That routine doesn't look too taxing, so at least I can't give you a definite 'Yes'. But as Dave Liepman's answer suggests, it's highly individual and you will probably not be able to tell if a routine is too much in advance. I'd say go for it and try how it works out for you in the long run. Once you exhibit symptoms of overtraining, though, you should step back and rethink your approach.

Comment: Here's an answer I gave to another question that I think is relevant: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/11495/5071

Comment: Are you using the proper progressions in the book? Why no bridge or handstand work? (haven't looked at the book in a while, can't remember the exact program)

Answer (score 1):

One. Overtraining is person-specific. Most given routines could overtrain one person while leaving another atrophying from insufficient effort.

Two. In general, alternating muscle groups doesn't prevent overtraining. You can absolutely overtrain while using such a method.